# Прозрачный JTextField

Tags: java

Добрый день. Есть Таблица `JTable`, одной из колонок которой присвоен самописный рендерер, который устанавливает в ячейки этого столбца `JTextField`. При выделении строки таблицы, она подсвечивается синим цветом, но ячейка с `JTextField` остаётся с белым фоном. Как можно сделать `JTextField` прозрачным или устанавливать ему фон при выделении строки? `.setOpaque(false)` не помогает.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решён следующим образом:

```
public class CurrencyTableCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer{    
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,   int col) {
        JTextField cell = new JTextField();
        cell.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        if(isSelected){
            cell.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            cell.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        }
        if(value!=null && (double)value>0) {
            cell.setText(String.format("%.2f", value));         
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```